# How to make QAM (quadrature amplitude modulation) of a square or sinc wave signal？

Tags: digital-logic, modulation, qam

I found this discussion of QAM in a communications text book and internet.

> "...load it into Matlab using `imread()`, which will give you an array of
>   `RxCx3` integers for an RGB colour image. Serialise however you want
>   (e.g. using `reshape()` to get a `1x(R*C*3)` vector). Add FEC and
>   interleaving/puncturing if desired. Once you know how many bits/symbol
>   you are using (QPSK would be 2, 16-QAM would be 4 etc.) then you can
>   split each element of your array up into groups of bits (e.g. 2 at a
>   time, 4 at a time... if 6 or 12 at a time you'd need to work with
>   pairs of elements), apply Gray coding or whatever mapping scheme you
>   wish to use to map each group of bits to a complex number, then put
>   that in the array elements corresponding to data-bearing carriers of
>   your frequency-domain vector. Continue until it is full. Populate the
>   pilot carriers that you wish to use with the desired symbols. Take the
>   inverse FFT of the frequency-domain vector. Voilà, a baseband OFDM
>   symbol in the time domain. Continue until you've used up all your
>   image data."

But I read the next formula in one paper, and I do not know how to express the sinc or square waveform into  $$ f(t) = A(t)\exp(j\theta(t) ) $$ and I do not see how to connect this equation with the method described above.

Can someone help me to figure out this?

Thanks a lot!

[image: base band signal can be expressed this]

[image: QAM modulation formula]

Comment: QAM is a *digital* modulation scheme. It takes digital data and modulates it onto a carrier. A sinc pulse is not digital data. A sampled and quantised version of a sinc pulse would be digital.

Comment: thanks Tom.  I get it. the sinc pulse is digital data stored in the ram of FPGA . if i do the QAM modulation of the sinc pulse , the output waveform is not a SINC shape pulse .is this right ?

Comment: No, the output will no look like a Sinc pulse, it will look like a series of tones with varying phase - digital 1's and 0's represented on carriers.

Comment: yes！ it is same with my idea.So i can not figure out the formula in the paper.